# clear text in a textfield or label in a cell by button action

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have some text fields and labels in cells in a tableView that I need to reset to empty on a button press.  I cannot do this with a reloadData call and setting everything in cellForRowAtIndexPath to @"" because there are situations where the table will be reloaded and i need to retain values.

So the only option is for me to somehow loop through every textfield or label and individually set their texts to @"".  But how do I access a cell, then pull out the textfield or label?  keep in mind my Table also consists of different types of custom cells.

I figured it would be best to do it with tags maybe but I don't know how to access a cell's 'viewWithTag' call.  If there even is such a thing.

*edit* added block of code where textfields are created

```
    BaseTableViewCell *baseCell = (BaseTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
    if (baseCell == nil){
        baseCell = [[BaseTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];

        BaseTextField *rightText = [[BaseTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 7, 150, 31)];
        rightText.placeholder = tableValues.key;
        rightText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        rightText.tag = (indexPath.section + 1) + (indexPath.row + 1);
        rightText.delegate = self;
        [baseCell addSubview:rightText];
    }
    NSLog(@"resetting text");
    baseCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    baseCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    baseCell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    baseCell.textLabel.text = tableValues.value;

    return baseCell;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do this for text field and labels in all the rows of the table? (not necessarily every text field and label in those cells, but for certain ones in every row)?

Comment: yes.  every row, but not necessarily every label or textfield

Comment: The calculation for tag is wrong; will only work if you only have 1 section.  e.g. section 0; row 3 equals section 2 row 2: (0+1) + (2+1) = 4; (1+1)+(1+1)=4

Comment: Also, "rightText" is only populated for newly created cells.  If you re-use a cell; the 'rightText' part of your cell is not populated.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @Dave the cells are set to be re-used, so when it needs a new cell, the text field will either already be there, or created.

Comment: @Jesse, I was just pointing out that you only populate it with data when it's created.  If it's always static content, why not create it in your BaseTableViewCell subclass.

Comment: the labels at the start are always empty as well as the textfields.  a user can put data in a text field via keyboard and can put values in the labels by selecting the row, going to another screen, making a choice, and then the label is populated with that choice.  i just need a way to wipe all that clean.  nothing i want to clear is really being populated by a data model.  its all user input.

Answer (score 2):

Issues like this tend to resolve themselves if you have a "data model" and treat it as "the truth".  In other words, always populate every cell of your tableview from your data.  You can have a simple array or two, or something more complex.  If you want to zap anything, zap the values in the model and reload the table.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564077/reload-only-a-subview-of-a-custom-uitableviewcell/14564367#14564367) will help you loop through your tableview if you want to do things that way; however, I recommend you update your data and call reload tableview.

Comment: this is actually how I have things set up.  I have an array of data that populates everything.  However my textfields start empty simply because i don't assign any text to it.  But it has data values associated with it that i cannot erase.

Comment: How do they go from empty to populated?  You update your model and reload the table?  Could you simply introduce a flag like "hideLabels"; and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath check the flag to determine if you use data from your model or blank/hide the label?  The rule remains - always ask your model for the data.  This is what folks will expect when maintaining your app.

Answer (score 0):

use UITableViews

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells
```

which gives you all the cells then loop through the cells subviews and reset the labels.

Comment: how do you loop through the cell's subviews?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746478/how-can-i-loop-through-all-subviews-of-a-uiview-and-their-subviews-and-their-su

Answer (score 0):

There is a UITableView property called `visibleCells`, which is an array of all of the cells you can see. Is that all that you need to change? Otherwise you would need loop through all of the cells and set the text fields to @"" like you said, using `-numberOfSections`, `-numberOfRowsInSection`, and `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: No, i need to loop through all the cells using numberofsections, numberofrowsinsect etc.  I just didnt know how to get access to the cells.  tableView.visibleCells seems like it would work but im still confused on how i would loop through.  i wont have access to # of sections and rows etc with just an array of visible cells

Comment: Visible cells is just if you wanted to use the cells on screen. It's an array so you can iterate through it like any array. 

If you need to do all of them, you can find out the total number of cells by using those numberOf.. methods, and then call cellForRowAtIndexPath: on each cell (row) number.

Answer (score 0):

UIView has a tag property you can set.

```
UITextField *textField = [UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 28)];
textField.tag = 20;
```

Generally, UITableView will reuse cells so you may have an issue when the cell reload different content.

You should look at managing your data separately from the table view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're question correctly, you don't do this by accessing the cells, but by changing the array that you use to populate the cells. Set whatever field in your custom objects, or a value in a dictionary (if you're using an array of dictionaries) to @"".

Comment: for the labels, this is possible.  But its not for my textfields.  I dont initialize any text inside the fields from the start (even though  there is hidden data for them)

Comment: @JesseDurham, how do you get the value into the text field? By user action? If so, then that value should be added to your array anyway, so that when you scroll away from them and come back, the value will still be there.

Comment: the text fields currently seem to be doing that already on their own.  i can even change views on the nav controller and go back, reload data, and the text fields hold the user typed data...  I dont add the values typed in until another condition is met. (a different button)

Comment: @JesseDurham, I don't know how that's possible without grabbing that value from somewhere. Where does that value come from when the table reuses a cell? Are these dynamic table view cells?

Comment: No, they are re-usable cells.  TBH I dont know how its holding the values either.  But I noticed if i try the method of reloading data and setting textfield text to @"" it doesn't change.  it still holds user inputted text.  I'll update the original question with my cell creation

Comment: @JesseDurham, how many rows do you have in your table now? Is it enough that the table needs to reuse cells.

Comment: currently there are about 12 with hardcoded data.  However this is dynamic and eventually there could be a situation where they need to be reused.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24207/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jesse-durham)